# Scalar product on arrays

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the real vector space $V$ consisting of all arrays with their elements in $\Bbb{R}$.
Is there any example of a scalar product on $V$?

More formally, assuming $V=\{(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...), a_i \in \Bbb{R}\}$ is there a function $(\cdot |\cdot):V\times V \to \Bbb{R}$ such that:
$$\begin{align} 
&(1) \quad(x|x)\geq0, \quad \forall x \in V \\
&(2) \quad (x|x)=0 \iff x=0 \\
&(3) \quad (x+y,z)=(x|z)+(y|z), \quad \forall x,y,z \in V \\
&(4) \quad (\alpha x|y)=\alpha(x|y), \quad \forall x,y \in V, \forall \alpha \in \Bbb{R} \\ 
&(5) \quad (x|y)=(y|x), \quad \forall x,y \in V\end{align} \\$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V$ is really just the set of sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, then no, since $(x|x)$ is not even well-defined (what if $x = (1,1,1,\dots)$?) But if you add the requirement that all sequences must be square summable (that is, $V = \{a_1,a_2,\dots)\text{ such that }\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2<\infty)$, then you can take $(\cdot|\cdot)$ to just be the standard dot product, i.e.,
$$(x|y) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i.$$
In this case, the space $V$ is called $\ell^2$, read aloud as "little ell two".

Comment: My question was about existence of such function $(\cdot | \cdot) : V \times V \to \Bbb{R} $ where $V$ consists of **all** sequences. Maybe there is no such function, but how can I prove that? P.s. Thanks for the special case of V, and according $(\cdot | \cdot)$

Comment: Are you looking for a full proof? Or just an answer? The answer is no. The function $(\cdot|\cdot)$ you are looking for is called an *inner product*, and it is a somewhat deep fact that $\ell^2$ is the only sequence space on which you can define an inner product, and that inner product is the the standard dot product. The proof comes from what is called the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces).